# get first Child of NavHostFragment

Tags: android

Based on this answer, I tried the solution but I'm getting the fragment as null.

[How to find a child Fragment with Navigation Architecture components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52987205/how-to-find-a-child-fragment-with-navigation-architecture-components)

Within **MainActivity.kt** I have this code.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    supportActionBar?.title = "Product List"
  println(nav_host_fragment.childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.productListFragment))
}
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_host_fragment" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And the **nav_host_fragment.xml** looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/products"
        app:startDestination="@id/productListFragment">

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/productListFragment"
            android:name="ProductListFragment"
            android:label="ProductListFragment" >
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**Lateral Thinking**

or do I've to work within `ProductListFragment.kt` -> `onViewCreated` and reach out to activity from there.

Comment: I tried to get the fragment in onCreate, and I couldn't find a way... If you want to communicate with activity, doing it in `onViewCreated` makes more sense.