# What objects are non-null type in my part of code ? I have kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.String exception

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

```
 fun loadData(){

    db?.collection("information")?.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if(exception != null){
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext,exception.localizedMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        else{
            if(snapshot != null){
                var documents = snapshot.documents
                for(document in documents){
                    var authorName = document.get("authorName") as String  
                    var bookName = document.get("bookName") as String
                    var url = document.get("url") as String

                    authorNameFromFbList?.add(authorName)
                    bookNameFromFbList?.add(bookName)
                    urlFromFbList?.add(url)

                }




            }

                }
                val adapter = MainAdapter(authorNameFromFbList!!,bookNameFromFbList!!,urlFromFbList!!)
                recyclerView.adapter = adapter
        }
    }
```

> **strong text**
>   In my code authorName bookName and url are type of Any and I recognized a string arraylist to add..So I think that ı should do type casting from any to String

Comment: Did you take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949024/kotlin-typecastexception-null-cannot-be-cast-to-non-null-type-com-midsizemango ?

Comment: Oh thank you I got it..There is a problem at my "url" code.My url arraylist doesn't work and I did it..